# What is it called when someone hates disabled people?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, word-usage

I’m having an argument with someone else who keeps telling me that racism is hating any kind of person. He keeps telling me that racism is sexism, etc.

I just want to know what the term for a person that hates disabled people (like mentally or physically disabled people) would be so I can prove him wrong. I know that’s a little ridiculous, but whatever.

Comment: show him a dictionary and then let it go. he'll eventually use the word in the wrong place with the wrong person and get sorted out in a more meaningful way. in terms of hatred of disabled people, i'd call that prejudice.

Comment: The other person seems to be confusing *racism* with *bigotry*

Comment: "Racism" clearly means bigotry based on race.

Comment: Finding such a word would not prove your friend wrong. If there were a word that meant prejudice against all people of Korean descent, that prejudice would still be racism.

Comment: If racism is prejudice against race, and ageism is prejudice against age, why wouldn't prejudice against the disabled be disableism?

Comment: It's called sick.

Comment: Persons such as this are commonly known as "losers".

Answer (score 32):

There is apparently a word - ***ableism*** - which describes people who are prejudiced against the disabled.

The word is confirmed by the OED, with the following meaning:

> Discrimination in favour of able-bodied people; prejudice against or
>   disregard of the needs of disabled people.

Comment: You were nine seconds late. :)

Comment: @tchrist Yes my apologies. I will not delete since my response does confirm that the OED is on-side with this.

Comment: Don’t you dare delete! I was just teasing!!

Comment: Not the best word, though, but maybe still the best one there is. The overuse of the word "racist" has diluted all -ist words in seriousness, like "ableist" or "ageist".

Comment: @user3932000, it may be not the best one, but it's the only one I've heard (or read, in Tumblr) in actual usage.

Comment: @user3932000: The idea that the word racist is overused is controversial and I would say highly political. Rather it seems to be underused by people not familiar with anti-racist thought, reserved only for overt acts of hate or intentional discrimination rather than covering the full spectrum of implicit associations, internalized prejudice, and systemic power structures that reinforce racial inequality.

Comment: @R. What is needed, in my view, is that all these separate notions of *racism*, *ageism*, *sexism*, *discrimination by sexual orientation* etc, be replaced by a single concept known simply as *prejudice*, or *discrimination*. It should be equally reprehensible to discriminate against fat people, or those with less than glamorous looks, as it is by race or gender. Many people suffer discrimination by social class. Anything which judges fitness by anything other than the actual requirements (e.g. to do a job) should be considered *prejudice*. We need a *General Law of Discrimination*.

Comment: @WS2: They really can't, or at least the idea that they can be is a political position, not a statement of fact or a noncontroversial idea. In any case the comments here are not the place for such a discussion.

Answer (score 21):

People who use *racist* these days to mean nothing more than prejudiced are diluting the brand.  According to [Oxford Dictionaries Online](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/racist), a *racist* is:

> A person who shows or feels discrimination or prejudice against people of other **races**, or who believes that a particular **race** is superior to another

So racism is about race. Period.

There are various, more specific words for what you are talking about. [Per the eponymous Wikipedia entry on *handicapism*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handicapism):

> *Handicapism* is a sociological term, which describes a theory and a set of practices that promote unequal and unfair treatment, discrimination and oppression of peoples with apparent or assumed disability, a concept like to racism or sexism.

But then also there is this, [again from Wikipedia’s eponymous entry on *ableism*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ableism):

> *Ableism* or *ablism* (/ˈeɪblɪzəm/) is a form of discrimination or social prejudice against people with disabilities. It may also be referred to as *disability discrimination, ablecentrism, physicalism, handicapism*, and *disability oppression*. It includes apotemnophobia and dysmorphophobia. It is also sometimes known as *disablism*, although there is some dispute as to whether ableism and disablism are synonymous, and some people within disability rights circles find the latter term’s use inaccurate. Discrimination faced by those who have or are perceived to have a mental disorder is sometimes called mentalism rather than ableism.

But if you really want to get somebody’s dander up, you could call them a *crippist*: someone displaying prejudice against the crippled.

Comment: In London back in the 1980s there used to be a home for physically disabled people which straddled the boundary of two London boroughs, one Labour controlled, and one (more leafy suburban) which was Conservative controlled.  Approaching from the Labour side (I think it was Enfield) there was a sign warning traffic to *Take Care, Disabled Persons Crossing*. Approaching from the other direction the sign read *Cripples Crossing*. It caused some mirth in the media.

Comment: @WS2 That’s hilarious!

Comment: @WS2 That's so mirthist.

Comment: @tchrist: Not so hilarious for the ratepayers footing the bill for changing the signs when boundaries change or councils change tribe.

Answer (score 1):

Your friend is obviously misinformed and the word for hatred of disabled is ableism, ageism for those whom are older, transmisia for those who are transgender, and Homomisia for hatred of gay people.

Comment: Welcome to SE EL&U. Please read the [Introductory Tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) for new users. At SE we're looking for [answers](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) that provide some explanation and context. Please explain why your answer is right, ideally with [citations](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). Otherwise how is the poster or anyone else to know whether your answer is correct or not? Answers that don't include explanations may be [removed](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers).